# No redefinition information in the transcript file

Tags: logging

The [fntguide](https://ctan.mirror.twds.com.tw/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf#page=23) says that:

> `\DeclareTextSymbol {⟨cmd⟩} {⟨encoding⟩} {⟨slot⟩}`
>
> > This command defines a text symbol with slot `⟨slot⟩` in the encoding. For
> > example, the definition of `\ss` in the `OT1` encoding is: `\DeclareTextSymbol{\ss}{OT1}{25}`. It does not produce an error if the command has already been defined but *logs
> > the redefinition in the transcript file*.

OK. Let me redefine the text symbol `\ss` as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\ss}{OT1}{28} % 28 is the slot occupied by \o
\begin{document}
\ss\o
\end{document}
```

The output is as expected (double ø). But there is no redefinition information in the log file. Why?

Comment: hmm I think fontenc is wrong. You are 30 years late reporting this....

Comment: Maybe the fontenc should be updated hhh@DavidCarlisle

Comment: But I think the log info is important in some cases.

Comment: I meant fontguide not fntenc of course. yes we should fix one way or another    you could raise an issue at github so we don't forget https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/

Comment: OK. I'll open an issue.